# Modeling time series binary data in R

Tags: time-series, binary-data

I have time series binary data with other explanatory variables (qualitative and quantitative). I would like to see pattern of events over the time, and influences of different variables using R. I am novice in stat and R. A detailed answer will be highly appreciated. The structure of data is as follow:

```
1. Event   Year     Season    Sex     Age   Vehicle
2. 0       2014      Winter    M      50     CAR 
3. 1       2015      Summer    F      30     BUS
```

Here 0 indicates injured and 1 indicates death. I want to see if the road accidents by different type of vehicles (e.g. car, bus, motorcycle etc) have a consistent pattern by year, season, age and sex ?

Comment: You can always start with simple logistic regression. Do not forget to consider including season and yearly dummies to account for seasonal variation.